# scipy L-BFGS-B optimizer with different step size per dimension

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, scipy

How can I adjust the optimizer to use a different step size for each DOF? When I print the parameters the step size seems to the the same per dimension.

Any other alternative optimizer that can facilitate this?

```
result = minimize(
        error_func,
        x0,
        method='L-BFGS-B',
        options={
            'disp': verbose,
            # 'maxiter': 1000,
            # 'ftol': 1.0E-8,
        }
)
```

Comment: took me a little while to figure out what a "spicy" optimizer was (now edited to "scipy" ...)

Comment: hail to autocomplete!

Comment: The step-size is determined by line-search. If you are not familiar with it, don't expect it to be possible (even in theory). [Intro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions). (also *gradient-descent* != *L-BFGS-B*)